# Get a value of object field inside fields_for loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

In the following scenario, I need to check the value of the object property in the `fields_for` loop.

```
<%= f.semantic_fields_for :review_details do |rd| %>
  <%= rd.input :review_criteria_id, :as=>:hidden %>
<% end %>
```

As in the loop, `:review_criteria_id` is rendered as hidden field, but I have a scenario, where I have to print some more information if it is a specific criteria. How can I get the value of `review_criteria_id` in the loop.
I used:

```
rd.review_criteria_id
```

But since `rd` is the formtastic object, so I couldn't get the value of `:review_crieteria_id`.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Formtastic adds additional features to the Rails code, but doesn't take away existing functionality so the following should work for you:

```
rd.object.review_criteria_id
```

'object' can be used in plain Rails form helpers to access the underlying bound object, and Formtastic honours this convention.

Comment: I'd add that you can find this by debugging the view. Adding a debug statement (in this case byebug) `<% byebug %>` inside the `fields_for` block gives a person access to the builder object itself. You can then call `methods` on said class and start investigating.

Answer (score 12):

I got it, I can use

```
rd.object.review_criteria_id
```

`object` is the default wrapper object for the `fields_for` loop.