# check if nested form records are null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can I check if some record in the nested form is null? I am trying this but it does not work

```
<%= f.fields_for :detallepromo do |builder| %>
  <% if builder.Monto == nil %>

  <div class="well center-block">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h3 class="col-md-5">Promocion Base:</h3>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <%= builder.label :Monto,"Monto:", class: "control-label col-md-2" %>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= builder.text_field :Monto, class: "form-control  mensaje_fechafinal" %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
<% end >
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4535296/511374

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? You should describe what you expect to obtain, and what is happening instead. Also, It looks like your HTML is missing a closing `</div>`, and the last `<% end %>` is malformatted. Is it possible this is the reason your code doesn't work?

Comment: @tompave Thanks for the answer, I spect to obtain for example: where builder.Monto == 1 then show the form with another data, depending on each record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Monto` is a property of your `ActiveRecord` model, then you can't access it directly on the `FormBuilder` object.

Try with:
`<% if builder.object.Monto.nil? %>`

Answer (score 1):

how, if like this:

```
    <% if :detallepromo? %>
      <p>bla.bla..</p>
    <% else %>
    <%= f.fields_for :detallepromo do |builder| %>
       <div class="well center-block">
         <div class="form-group">
           <h3 class="col-md-5">Promocion Base:</h3>
         </div>

     <div class="form-group">
       <%= builder.label :Monto,"Monto:", class: "control-label col-md-2" %>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= builder.text_field :Monto, class: "form-control  mensaje_fechafinal"%>
      </div>
  <% end %>
<% end >
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I spect to obtain for example: where builder.Monto == 1 then show the form with another data, depending on each record

Answer (score 1):

Try Following.

```
<%= f.fields_for :detallepromo do |builder| %>
  <% if builder.Monto.nil? %>

  <div class="well center-block">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h3 class="col-md-5">Promocion Base:</h3>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <%= builder.label :Monto,"Monto:", class: "control-label col-md-2" %>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= builder.text_field :Monto, class: "form-control  mensaje_fechafinal" %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
<% end >
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, this throws me undefined method `Monto' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x84689528> I dont know why,

Comment: I spect to obtain for example: where builder.Monto == 1 then show the form with another data, depending on each record